# User name in Qt project

Tags: qt

I am working on two different machines (two different usernames) on the same project. I have to specify a path in the Qt project file, which contains my username. Is there a way for the Qt project to figure out my username? I have tried to use the $USER variable:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/$USER/mongo-client-install/include
```

but it does not work. However in shell I can use the $USER variable. I am using Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use relative paths. `NEVER` use absolute paths for this kind of tasks.

AFAIK Mac OS has some paths(include or lib paths) which are accessible from everywhere because they are added in the system PATH variable. Install your libraries there or add `/Users/$USER/mongo-client-install/include` to your `PATH`. This way you will be easily be able to `#include <myLibraryHeader>` in your sources.

I'm not a Mac user and I'm not 100% sure about this but as far as I remember the libraries should be installed in `/Developer/Library/` folder.